# Wordpress add_filter condition for widget area

Tags: php, wordpress

I have added a custom template for an [image widget](https://wordpress.org/plugins/image-widget/) which is defined in functions.php:

```
add_filter('sp_template_image-widget_widget.php','my_template_filter');
 function my_template_filter($template) {
 return get_template_directory() . '/widget-templates/image-widget-custom.php';
}
```

The contents of this template (image-widget-custom.php) are shown here:

```
<?php
/**
 * Widget template. This template can be overriden using the  "sp_template_image-widget_widget.php" filter.
      * See the readme.txt file for more info.
      */

 // Block direct requests
 if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
    die('-1');

 echo '<div class="col-sm-3 footer-blocks">';

 echo $before_widget;

 $output = "";
 $output .= '<a href="' . $instance[link] . '">';
 $output .= '<div class="hover-wrapper">';
 $output .= '<div class="hover-inner">';
 $output .= '<div class="hover-border">';
 $output .= '<h2 class="text-uppercase">' . $instance[title] . '</h2>';
 $output .= '</div>';
 $output .= '</div>';
 $output .= '<img class="img-responsive" src="' . $instance[imageurl] . '" alt="Footer image">';
 $output .= '</div>';
 $output .= '</a>';

echo $output;


echo $after_widget;

echo '</div>';
?>
```

The only thing is, I want the widget to be formatted for a specific widget area, not everywhere it is used on the wordpress website. The area I want the template applied to is in the footer:

```
<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'footer-blocks' ); ?>
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

One way - assuming you can modify theme template files - is to add the filter *just before* the sidebar call, and then remove the filter *just after* the sidebar call.

Remove the `add_filter` that you have in your theme files, and then modify your code like so:

```
 <?php 
    // Add the filter just before the sidebar is called
    add_filter('sp_template_image-widget_widget.php','my_template_filter');
    // Call the sidebar, which will use your custom template
    dynamic_sidebar( 'footer-blocks' );
    // Remove the filter to ensure any other sidebars do not use custom template
    remove_filter('sp_template_image-widget_widget.php','my_template_filter');
 ?>
```

Note that [remove_filter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_filter) will ensure that any OTHER calls to the widget will not be filtered with your custom template.

**Alternate Method (preferred / better):**

The more "WordPress Way" to do this would be to leverage the `dynamic_sidebar_before` and `dynamic_sidebar_after` functions, and in doing so you can check *which sidebar* is being loaded, and add the filter ONLY for the correct sidebar(s).  This code would go in your theme's functions.php file:

```
add_action( 'dynamic_sidebar_before', 'my_sidebar_checker', 10, 2);
add_action( 'dynamic_sidebar_after', 'my_sidebar_checker_after', 10, 2);

function my_sidebar_checker( $index, $bool ) {
    if ( 'footer-blocks' == $index ) {
        // Add the filter just before the sidebar is called
        add_filter('sp_template_image-widget_widget.php','my_template_filter');
    }
}

function my_sidebar_checker_after( $index, $bool ) {
    if ( 'footer-blocks' == $index ) {
        // Remove the filter to ensure any other sidebars do not use custom template
        remove_filter('sp_template_image-widget_widget.php','my_template_filter');
    }
}
```

Comment: Great thank you, I used your alternate method and this works well for me.